# Android: Twitter link is not working in phonegap app

Tags: android, twitter, cordova

I am new to phonegap app development. In my app I had embedded twitter timeline feed using following script in my html page:

```
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

The script is working fine, and it gave the results also. Below is the screenshot:

[image: App Screenshot]

But, when click on image link or image: which is as follows, it opens blank:
Here, is the link:

[pic.twitter.com/CJMo0nyFmH](http://pic.twitter.com/CJMo0nyFmH)

I tried to open the link on my mobile's browser, and it worked perfectly. But, same is not working in app. Please help.

**Update:**

This is my html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>info</title>
<link href="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile.theme-1.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet"     type="text/css"/>
<link href="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile.structure-1.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="themes/f.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="styles/dst_mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="styles/jquery.zrssfeed.min.js" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="styles/jquery.zrssfeed.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="jquery-mobile/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="phonegap.js"></script>
<script src="code/jquery.zrssfeed.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!--<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#news').rssfeed('http://dstinc1913.wordpress.com/category/News/feed/', {
limit: 10, 

    });

});

</script>-->

</head> 
<body> 
<div align="center">
<div data-role="page" id="info" data-theme="c">
<div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
    <h1>News</h1>
    <a href="index.html" data-icon="home" class="ui-btn-right" rel="external">Home</a>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
<div><a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/DSTinc1913" data-widget-id="350541068783210496">Tweets by @DSTinc1913</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s) [0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/KV7Px/)
I did no change in codes, Its working for me !! ?
What's the issue here !?

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>info</title>
<link href="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile.theme-1.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet"     type="text/css"/>
<link href="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile.structure-1.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="themes/f.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="styles/dst_mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="styles/jquery.zrssfeed.min.js" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="styles/jquery.zrssfeed.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="jquery-mobile/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="phonegap.js"></script>
<script src="code/jquery.zrssfeed.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!--<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#news').rssfeed('http://dstinc1913.wordpress.com/category/News/feed/', {
limit: 10, 

    });

});

</script>-->

</head> 
<body> 
<div align="center">
<div data-role="page" id="info" data-theme="c">
<div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
    <h1>News</h1>
    <a href="index.html" data-icon="home" class="ui-btn-right" rel="external">Home</a>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
<div><a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/DSTinc1913" data-widget-id="350541068783210496">Tweets by @DSTinc1913</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s) [0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT** : Use this code to open links in childbrowser. This may help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>InAppBrowser.removeEventListener Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // Global InAppBrowser reference
    var iabRef = null;

    function iabLoadStart(event) {
        //alert(event.type + ' - ' + event.url);
    }

    function iabLoadStop(event) {
        alert(event.type + ' - ' + event.url);
    }

    function iabLoadError(event) {
        alert(event.type + ' - ' + event.message);
    }

    function iabClose(event) {
         //alert(event.type);
         iabRef.removeEventListener('loadstart', iabLoadStart);
         iabRef.removeEventListener('loadstop', iabLoadStop);
         iabRef.removeEventListener('loaderror', iabLoadError);
         iabRef.removeEventListener('exit', iabClose);
    }

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {

    }

    function inappbrowser()
    {
         iabRef = window.open('http://google.com', '_blank', 'location=yes');
         iabRef.addEventListener('loadstart', iabLoadStart);
         iabRef.addEventListener('loadstop', iabLoadStop);
         iabRef.removeEventListener('loaderror', iabLoadError);
         iabRef.addEventListener('exit', iabClose);
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>
  THis is demo for the inappbrowser
  <button onclick="inappbrowser()" type="submit">Click me</button>
  </h1>



  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Its working but on browser(I tested on both, my desktop and device). It shows feed correctly in my same as the screenshot, that I had posted above. But, when I click on any link in the feed, within my app, a blank page opens up.

Comment: Let me integrate to phonegap and check... wait !

Comment: EDITED my post, see the changes. It may help.

Comment: Ok, I will try and let you know the results.

Comment: I figured out that if click on someone's profile for e.g at  @mayorvincegray, in the first tweet, as shown in the screenshot, it opens up without any problem. But, if click on url of an image it opens blank.